# Facebook Api: Access detailed education info

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I try to get more information about a persons eduaction, but the only result I get for the parameter education is this:

```
{
  "education": [
{
  "school": {
    "id": "106192892753205", 
    "name": "Karl-Bosch-Schule"
  }, 
  "year": {
    "id": "293652345609608", 
    "name": "2012"
  }, 
  "type": "High School"
}, 
 ...
```

How can I get access to the further information like when the person started and finished school? Or their degree?

Thanks

EDIT: Request goes to:

```
/me?fields=education
```

Comment: Hi Frank - have you had any success with that so far? I fear it might not be possible :( If you haven't had any success I might start a bounty on this question to get some more attention to it.

Comment: Hey, it seems like facebook will have to update their api - It is not possible to get more information on this even though the user has entered the data

Comment: I thought that was the case... Have you looked into using FQL queries? From a quick overview of it's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) it would return the same data as the JS SDK :(

Comment: I'm not able to use the JS SDK in my project therefore I don't have any possibility until facebook updates this (hopefully they will someday) - still cannot understand why since they force me to ask for the friendlist i think they could provide this data

Comment: It makes no sense indeed... You said that you can't use the JS SDK - is there another SDK that allows you to get that data?